# different hosting account, same URL?

Tags: hosting, domain, subdomain

Our client has a website at www.myclient.com. They want a new site created at www.myclient.com/newsite and for us to host it.

Is it possible to have www.myclient.com hosted on one server/network and www.myclient.com/newsite hosted on another server/network? How?

If not possible - is it possible using subdomains (newsite.myclient.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both sites could run under the same DNS name, but for the "second" site, you would need to set up a proxy (mod_proxy if you're using apache) to proxy requests through to the second server.

For your second question, yes of course, with a subdomain it is certainly possible to run the two sites on separate hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'url rewriting'.

- For IIS, check [here](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)
- For Apache, please check [there](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)