# Forum for my blog: Should I make it as subdomain or as subfolder?? forum.example.com or example.com/forum

Tags: subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [different hosting account, same URL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/275701/different-hosting-account-same-url)

Hello guys,

I have a blog and I want to add a forum as my community is big enough...

My blog is in Wordpress and I will buy a popular forum platform to create the forum. I don't care about the integration of the two platforms (WP + forum software) I just care about how forum should be setup.

a) forum.example.com

or

b) example.com/forum

My concern:

There is a good chance that the forum itself will need a dedicated server. I know that a subdomain (solution a) can has a dedicated server, my question is can also solution b work with a separate dedicated server?

in other words can "example.com" has a dedicated server and "example.com/forum" has another separate dedicated server? or just "forum.example.com" can has a separate dedicated server?

Comment: Thank you for this link, yes this is exactly what i am asking. So if i got the answer of that question correctly, it is possible for my solution a via a mod_proxy, and of course solution b can work also. is that correct?

Comment: correction on my above comment solution a i meant solution b, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the two services on separate servers at some point, you should use a separate hostname for each. The only way your solution b) could work is if you have a reverse proxy server that sends the requests to the correct server, which would be complicating things for you. Best option is to go with forum.example.com for your forums. You could also set up a redirect rule so that example.com/forum redirects to forum.example.com

Comment: Thats what i was suspecting but i needed a second opinion. Yes subdomain solution is what i will choose. Thank you barryj for your answer